# Как изменить цвет верхней панели в android?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, дизайн

Как изменить цвет верхней панели (которая сейчас зелёная) в android?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Эникейщик, не дубликат, меня интересует, как это сделать статическим образом, то есть чтобы цвет был постоянным

Comment: 100500 способов в зависимости и без зависимости от сдк: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android